# Can I print a booklet from an .indb instead of a .indd file

Tags: print-design, booklet

As best I can tell I can't print a booklet from an indesign book file that combines multiple indesign document files.  The prepare book for printing command seems to prepare it to be printed to be perfect bound but I need to print it using the booklet printing dialogue window so that the book can be sewn together instead of glued together.  Does anyone know how to do this without having to make the whole book into one document file?  I've used formating that seems to disappear if I try to make it one document.

Comment: If there is no good answer for this, or if you are in a hurry: create a new InDesign document and place all of your current documents into it as "linked document". Then you won't have the formatting changes that you saw.